# Binding to a property of the object

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding, xamarin.android

I have a Label and I want to bind Text to a property of an object

```
public class MainCar: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      
        string typeCar;
        public string TypeCar
        {
            set
            {
                if (typeCar != value)
                {
                    typeCar = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TypeCar");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return typeCar;
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

In my Xaml code I have a label and I do not understand how to bind Text of my Label to object`s property TypeCar

XAML CODE

```
 <Label x:Name="label" FontSize="Large" Text="" />
```

BEHIND CODE

```
 public Car_add()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new TypesCar();
           
        }
```

VIEWMODEL CLASS

public class TypesCar
{

```
    public TypesCar()
    {
        var vm = new MainCar() { TypeCar = "Ford" };
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is very well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/)

```
<Label x:Name="label" FontSize="Large" Text="{Binding TypeCar}" />
```

then in the code behind

```
var vm = new MainCar() { TypeCar = "Ford" };
this.BindingContext = vm;
```

OR, if you are binding to a property on the SAME PAGE and NOT A VM

```
this.BindingContext = this;
```

note that if you want your UI to update as your VM changes, the VM must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: In my behind code I wrote   this.BindingContext = new TypesCar();
on this page I want to bind it,I can not to write this.BindingContext = vm;
I wrote that you said me,without this.BindingContext = VM; but it does not work

Comment: if you assign the property value after you assign the BindingContext you will need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: public class MainCar: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      
        string typeCar;
        public string TypeCar
        {
            set
            {
                if (typeCar != value)
                {
                    typeCar = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("TypeCar");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return typeCar;
            }
        }

Comment: public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }]

Comment: you don't need to do anything in the XAML.

Comment: how to bind TypeCar and Text in Label?

Comment: I already showed you that in my answer.  If you're still having problems, please edit your question and include the relevant code and take the time to format it so that it is readable.

Comment: that just shows your model class (which looks correct), where is the relevant XAML and code from your page?

Comment: Now I tried to only bind one Label to one property, because in my project I need to collect information from different functions to properties.And now I only  want to bind TypeCar to Label`s Text <Label x:Name="label" FontSize="Large" Text="" />

Comment: Again, my answer above shows exactly the syntax to use for the binding expression

Comment: It works if I add var vm = new MainCar() { TypeCar = "Ford" };
this.BindingContext = vm; in code behind of my Xaml,but when I add it on TypesCar it does not work

Comment: `Text="{Binding TypeCar}"`